# android app flip layout when I change language

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created an app on android studio using java.
I have a problem that when I change the language From English to Arabic the app flips 180 degrees (as mirror effect) as shown in the images.

I want to stop that from happening, how do I do that??

In English it is like this
[image]

And in Arabic this happens

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to prevent this? The language is supposed to be read from right to left, it would be very strange for an Arabic user to see otherwise.

Comment: @Pawel , Yes it was useful, Thank you

Comment: @HenryTwist, the problem is not the language, the problem is tat the buttons and other elements are being filliped and messed up.

Comment: Yes of course, but if you expect your app to be used with an Arabic language, you should surely make an effort to add RTL support?

Comment: @HenryTwist , Yes sure, I will try to do it one day. cancelling it is just a temporary solution for me at the moment, I just started 2days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling RTL on the app?

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application ...
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#SupportLayoutMirroring

Comment: @HenryTwist, I've edited my response